# Equal values do not equal to each other?

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, equality

I'm having a really weird equality problem here. I cannot for life find out what's wrong - it's extremely odd.

I have this function:

```
function escapeAll(t) {
    var res = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        res += "\\" + t[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now, why is this **false**?

```
escapeAll(":D")==="\:\D"
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf4vS/

Any ideas please? It's really driving me mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
escapeAll(":D")==="\\:\\D"
```

This return `true` ;)